# stop repetition of column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables related via id.

books:

```
book_id | book_name | year | publisher | slug
```

chapters:

```
chapter_id | book_id | chapter_name
```

Now when I query the database to find all the chapters related to a book like this:

```
SELECT book_name, chapter_name FROM ci_books, ci_chapters WHERE ci_books.book_id = ci_chapters.book_id AND slug = 'twelvers-dawn';
```

I get:

```
**book_name | chapter_name**
twelvers  | Rising Sun
twelvers  | Slow Down
twelvers  | Masochist
```

I get the name of the book repeating with each chapter, how can I a stop the name from repeating so that only the name shows once and all the chapters are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`GROUP_CONCAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with [**`GROUP_BY`**](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)

```
SELECT book_name, GROUP_CONCAT(chapter_name) AS chapter_names
FROM ci_books, ci_chapters 
WHERE ci_books.book_id = ci_chapters.book_id AND slug = 'twelvers-dawn'
GROUP BY book_name;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Now the next thing to do is replace the commas with line breaks in php.

Comment: use `str_replace(',', '<br>' $row['chapter_names']);`

Comment: I am using the Separator within group_concat but facing [other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907921/group-concat-with-php-to-add-individual-hyperlinks) , thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like:

```
SELECT book_name, GROUP_CONCAT(chapter_name) as ChapterNames 
FROM ci_books, ci_chapters 
WHERE ci_books.book_id = ci_chapters.book_id AND slug = 'twelvers-dawn'
GROUP BY book_name;
```

See resource [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Have added the above one as the answer because @John Conde answered first. Thank you all the same.

Comment: No problem @abushahin that's your prerogative and we here at SO ought to be happy helping one another not because we get points ;-) GOD bless and Happy Coding!