# Group_Concat with php to add individual hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, group-concat

I've got a query that retrieves from tables using group_concat so that I dont have repititions.

```
'SELECT book_name, chapter_slug, GROUP_CONCAT(chapter_name SEPARATOR "<br/>") as ChapterNames 
FROM ci_books, ci_chapters 
WHERE ci_books.book_id = ci_chapters.book_id AND slug = ' . $conn->quote($slug). '
GROUP BY book_name;'
```

Now the results are 
 separated which is good because I want to add hyperlinks to each however I am only getting one row that means the hyperlink is the same for all the chapterNames values.

```
book_name       chapter_slug   ChapterNames     
Twelvers Dawn   wonders        Wonders<br/>Rising
```

So now all the ChapterNames when hyperlinked via PHP are just the same. I can understand why, but how can I make it that each one has its own hyperlink.

Ideally, I would like this result or similar:

```
book_name      chapter_slug  ChapterNames   
Twelvers Dawn  wonders       Wonders
               rising        Rising
               movers        Movers
```

Comment: If you're selecting `book_name` and `chapter_slug` then you should also be grouping by `book_name` and `chapter_slug`. Nothing else makes sense.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks but then I am back to repetitive book_name, how can I keep this but elimate the repitition of book_name?

Comment: You're confusing data storage and retrieval with data display. Issues of data display should be handled at the presentation layer (assuming you have one). If you *don't* have a presentation then just a set up a couple of @prev/@next variables to handle the display logic. You do not need any aggregation.

Comment: I understand perhaps I should've made it more clear. I am using php to add hyperlinks so I have: foreach($data as $row) {
        print '<h2>'.$row['book_name'].'</h2>
  <p>'.$row['book_name'].'</p>
  <p><a href="'.$slug.'/'.$row['chapter_slug'].'">'.$row['ChapterNames'].'</a></p>';
 } which results in one hyperlink I want individual hyperlinks per chapter_name.

Comment: Update your question. Also, you seem to have a column called `chapter_slug` and another called `slug`. This is confusing.

Comment: I have overcome this by doing two separate select queries, one to get the name of the book and the other to retrieve the chapter names that belong to the book table.